# HttpWebRequest Authentication not working

Tags: c#, authentication, web, passwords, httpwebrequest

Alright, so I'm writing a program to access a RESTful service, but I first must provide authentication to the website. I have valid credentials and my entire code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace AccessAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string uri = "http://domainName/";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            string auth = CreateAuthorization("http://domainName/", "my\\username", "password");
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + auth;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        static string CreateAuthorization(string realm, string userName, string password)
        {
            string auth = ((realm != null) && (realm.Length > 0) ?
        realm + @"\" : "") + userName + ":" + password;
            auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(auth));
            return auth;
        }
    }
}
```

I've come this far using a few of the solutions posted on other forums. While this seemed to work out for some people, it doesn't for me. First off, I do KNOW that the credentials are accurate. I'm able to enter them over a web browser and they behave just as they should. Also, I made sure that any "\" in them (there is one in the username) is represented with a "\\" in the code. Every time I run this, though, I keep on getting back "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
Can anyone help me troubleshoot through this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does the REST service use basic authentication? a very common practice is to have a resource named "login" or "auth" or anything else, pass the credentials to it, get an authorization token and then use that token, you need to read the service documentation.to see which authorization mechanism uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to both Gusman and Prashant, your comments helped steer me in the correct direction and to eventual success. So Gusman, you were right, this wasn't just any authentication standard, it was using Window's IIS service. Googling how to do that with HttpWebRequest led me to building this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace AccessAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string uri = "http://domain.name/";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Now why this works while the other attempts didn't, I don't know. But the crux of it all seems to be based on just the line

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Which, by the way, Prashant, works when I don't use the whole http://domain.name/, just like you said.
Well, hopefully if anyone else is having this exact same problem they'll be able to find this thread and figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code, when the "auth" string is getting composed the auth string will look like this: "http://domainName/:my\username:password"

The auth string should really have the format: domainName\username:password (the domain name is optional).